# how to get a equal-match result from field which has array value in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my documents, I have a field which has an array of String.
like
weapon : ["Bland Blade", "Defender Quelthalas", "Thousand Lies", "Frozen Bonespike"]

I would like to get all the documents whose weapon field has "Frozen Bonespike".
not field which has one word - like "Frozen" or "Bonespike"
and not even field which contains "Frozen Bonespike" - like "Winter Frozen Bonespike"

I would like to get a field which has exactly equal string with query word

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you have to set your weapon field as type `keyword` and then run a terms search against it.

By default elasticsearch will create both text type field (lets say weapon) and keyword (weapon.keyword)

**Ingesting document**

```
POST test_seo/_doc
{
  "weapon": [
    "Bland Blade",
    "Defender Quelthalas",
    "Thousand Lies",
    "Frozen Bonespike"
  ]
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_seo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "weapon.keyword": {
        "value": "Frozen Bonespike"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to search by many different weapons you can use a `terms` query

```
POST test_seo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "weapon.keyword": [
        "Bland Blade",
        "Thousand Lies"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```